# Store map_overlap dask computation in original numpy array

Tags: python, dask, correlation, overlap

I want to achieve the following workflow (as an edge case in a larger project):

1. Create Dask Array from 2D numpy array
2. Correlate with map_overlap using depth=1 and no boundary, similar to dask_image.ndfilters.correlate
3. Compute and store dask array in original numpy array

I have trouble achieving step 3 without doubling memory usage. I get artifacts at the chunk boundaries when using dask_array.store(numpy_array, compute=True), but not when I use numpy_array = dask_array.compute().

My attempt at a minimum reproducible example which share my workflow is using dask_image.correlate:

```py
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import dask_image.ndfilters as da_ndf
def initalize_arrays():
    array = np.ones((150,100),dtype=np.uint8)
    dask_array = da.from_array(array,chunks=((8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6),
     (8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4)))
    return array, dask_array

array, dask_array = initalize_arrays()
weight_sums = da_ndf.correlate(dask_array,weights=np.ones((3,3)),mode='constant',cval=0.0)

weight_sums.store(array,compute=True)
array_store = array.copy()

array, dask_array = initalize_arrays()
weight_sums = da_ndf.correlate(dask_array,weights=np.ones((3,3)),mode='constant',cval=0.0)
array_compute = weight_sums.compute()
```

Image of the results, cannot embed images yet.
[Image of 2D arrays showing artifacts at chunk boundaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYWCC.png)

Comment: Which version of `dask` and `dask-image` do you use? I have versions `dask==2021.4.0`  and `dask-image==0.6.0`. I get identical results from `weight_sums.store(array,compute=True)` and `weight_sums.compute()` on mentioned versions.